# Meaning of mantra chanted before tantrik puja

Tags: mantras, worship, translation-request

For Kerala style puja done by priest, the following mantra is chanted before undertaking the puja which is a mix of Vaidik and tantrik style.

> susharmasi supratishthano brihadukshe namah:
>   Esha thayoni vishebhyastha devebhya:

सुशर्मासी सुप्रतिष्ठानो बृहदुक्षे नमः 
ऐषतयोनि विशेभ्यस्त देवेभ्य:

Please explain the meaning and purpose of the above mantra.
If not, word by word translation may be given.